# Which code is more effective? Why?

Tags: java, performance

I'm doing some programming exercises at the end of chapter four in "Introduction to Java Programming: Comprehensive Version" by Y. Daniel Liang.  On question 4.18 I came up with two different solutions.

Which solution(PatternLoop1 or PatternLoop2) is more effective and why?

```
public class PatternLoop1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 6; ++counter) {
            for (int counter2 = 0; counter2 <= counter; ++counter2) {
                System.out.print(counter2 + 1);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class PatternLoop2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int counter = 1; counter < 7; counter++) {
            for (int counter2 = 1; counter2 < 7 && counter2 <= counter; counter2++) {
                System.out.print(counter2);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither is more efficient.  The runtime will be utterly dominated by `System.out.print`.

Comment: I highly doubt some minor detail will make any difference when dealing with two loops of 6 iterations each.

Comment: Clayton - welcome to SO.  We can see that you're starting out and looking for a bit of a critique about your code ... effectively asking which one is "better".  Jon's been good and tried to help you out.  What you need to understand about the rest of the comments is that for code that is this *trivial*, there is no material benefit from producing the most highly "optimised" version. From a software engineering point of view, the better code would be the code that is most readily understandable (and thus maintainable).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: I hadn't noticed the `code-efficiency` tag before. The answer below is about how *effective* the solutions are - and the effectiveness of code includes how readable it is, IMO. (That's how effectively it expresses its aims.) The *efficiency* differences will be unmeasurably small.

Assuming the aim is to print 1, then 1 2, then 123 ... up to 123456 I'd go with something between the two, where all the numbers are the ones involved in the *output*:

```
for (int counter = 1; counter <= 6; counter++) {
    for (int counter2 = 1; counter2 <= counter; counter2++) {
        System.out.print(counter2);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Note that counter is always <= 6, so we don't need an extra check for `counter2` being <= 6.

Also note that *most* of the time we need numbers in the range [0, n) in my experience - the [1, n] requirement here is relatively rare. Of course it depends on what you're doing, but you should think of the *natural* way of expressing the range. If the natural inclination is to make the upper bound inclusive, use `<=`; if the natural inclination is to make the upper bound exclusive, use `<`.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  I'm just trying to get some input from you folks.  I'm a beginner looking for practice.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is that it doesn't matter. The JVM already optimizes code, and for a trivially difference like this, it will probably end up generating the same instructions anyway. Furthermore, optimization is a very complex problem and you can't just look at code and say it's faster. Actual performance depends on a lot of hidden things like the cache behavior of the processor. Lastly, you shouldn't try to make this kind of optimization in the first place. Don't bother unless you find a bottleneck with a measurable performance problem. Profile, profile, profile.